# localStorage undefined

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

with this `function`:

```
function appendToStorage(name, data) {
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (old === null) old = '';
    localStorage.setItem(name, old + data);
}
appendToStorage('oldData', $('textbox').value);
```

and this `html`:

```
<textarea name ="textbox" cols="50" rows="5">
say it...
</textarea><br>

<input type="submit" onclick="appendToStorage(name, data)"/>
```

I get `undefinedundefinedundefined...` on the console.

what I am missing?

Comment: Where do you get the `name` and `data` variables from, in the `onclick` handler?

Comment: Try debugging it using breakpoints.Certainly some value is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the textarea's value, and the storage key to `appendToStorage`.

So it is better to use a another method which does that an call that on click of the button like

```
<input type="submit" onclick="addTextArea();" />
```

then

```
function appendToStorage(name, data) {
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (old === null) old = '';
    localStorage.setItem(name, old + data);
}
addTextArea();

function addTextArea() {
    appendToStorage('oldData', $('textarea[name="textbox"]').val());//use .val() to get the value, also need to use attribute selecotr for name
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qkuenbys/)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve here, however the easiest solution is to let your appendToStorage function do the work:

```js
function appendToStorage (name) {
  
  // get the target element by it's name
  var el = document.querySelector('[name="' + name + '"]');
  
  // check we're getting the correct info
  console.log("[" + name + "]:", el.value);
  
  // save it to storage (you may also want to retrieve the last value and append it)
  window.localStorage.setItem(name, el.value);
}
```

```css
input {display: block; margin: 0 0 1em; } pre { font-size: 0.9em; display: block; margin: 0.5em 0; }
```

```html
<script>console.log = function () { document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(" "); }</script>
<textarea name="textbox" cols="50" rows="3">
say it...
</textarea>
<input type="submit" onclick="appendToStorage('textbox')"/>
<textarea name="textbox-again" cols="50" rows="3">
say it again...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="appendToStorage('textbox-again')"/>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Note: The above doesn't reflect best practice, however it does show how to retrieve a value from your textfield.